# Passing this object to inner function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function defined on another function, like so

```
function Test(message) {
    this.message = message;
}

Test.prototype.print = function() {
    console.log(this.message);
}

Test.prototype.print.polite = function() {
    console.log(this.message + ', please.');
}

var x = new Test('hello world');

x.print();
x.print.polite();
```

x.print() prints 'hello world' as expected, but x.print.polite() prints 'undefined, please', as opposed to 'hello world, please'.

I understand that this is because the context passed to the print.polite function is the print function. Is there, however, a way to access the 'this' of print from print.polite, short of explicitly adding it as a parameter? I'd like to retain the invocation semantic of print.polite(), instead of making it printPolite().

I'm fairly new to JavaScript, so I apologize if this is an inane question.

*Edit*

Based on the suggestions, I've modified my code like so, and it seems to work.

```
function Test(message) {
    this.message = message;
    this.print.that = this;
}

Test.prototype.print.polite = function() {
    console.log(this.that.message + ', please.');
}
```

Like you pointed out, though, it is a rather hacky solution. Isn't there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: That will set *Test.prototype.print.that* to the last created instance, so it will "work" only in that context, it will not work for the first *n-1* instances.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use `call` or `apply`, like this:

```
Test.prototype.print.polite.call(x);
```

This calls the function `Test.prototype.print.polite` with `x` as the context, or `this` value, and no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to keep the invocation semantic, but the implementation may be a bit ugly.

```
function Test(message) {
    var local = this;

    this.message = message;
    this.print = function() {
        console.log(local.message);
    };

    this.print.polite = function() {
        console.log(local.message + ", please.");
    };

    return this;
}
```

Note that this does not take advantage of the prototype at all.